# SwiftUI background Image fullScreen

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13

I am trying to make the background of screen to be Image not color. I want to know what should be the image sizes, and what to change in these values.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
             ZStack {
                Image("Home-BG")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
```

I want the image to be fit to screen in all iphone and ipad available devices.

Comment: I didn't really get what's the problem here. Your code make the image fill the screen as a background as expected. What is the result you get and what is the result you'd like to achieve?

Comment: what are image sizes should I use?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
    ZStack {            
        Image("BackGroundImage")
            .resizable()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
```